# Mysql Query takes too much time

Tags: mysql, database, query-performance

I need to get all the records from product table and only matching records from other tables.
I've mysql tables with upto 2000 records in the product table. The join query without group_concate and group by runs faster.
e.x the below query takes  0.6486 sec

```
SELECT *    FROM  `oc_product` 
LEFT JOIN  `oc_product_to_category` ON  `oc_product`.`product_id` =  `oc_product_to_category`.`product_id` 
LEFT JOIN  `oc_product_description` ON  `oc_product`.`product_id` =  `oc_product_description`.`product_id` 
LEFT JOIN  `oc_category_description` ON  `oc_product_to_category`.`category_id` =  `oc_category_description`.`category_id` 
LEFT JOIN  `oc_product_image` ON  `oc_product_to_category`.`product_id` =  `oc_product_image`.`product_id` 
LEFT JOIN  `oc_seo_data` ON  `oc_product`.`product_id` =  `oc_seo_data`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN  `oc_url_alias` ON  `oc_seo_data`.`url_alias_id` =  `oc_url_alias`.`url_alias_id`
```

When I use GROUP BY and CONCAT_GROUP it takes 18.4205 sec

```
    SELECT `oc_product_description`.`name` as `Product_Name`,`oc_product`.`price` as `PRICE`,`oc_url_alias`.`keyword` as `Product_Url`,`oc_product_image`.`image` as `Image Path`,GROUP_CONCAT(distinct `oc_category_description`.`name`) as `Category_name`,`oc_product`.`model` as `Product_Code` FROM `oc_product` LEFT JOIN  `oc_product_to_category` ON `oc_product`.`product_id` = `oc_product_to_category`.`product_id`
    LEFT JOIN `oc_product_description` ON `oc_product`.`product_id` = `oc_product_description`.`product_id`
    LEFT JOIN `oc_category_description` ON `oc_product_to_category`.`category_id` = `oc_category_description`.`category_id`
    LEFT JOIN `oc_product_image` ON `oc_product_to_category`.`product_id` = `oc_product_image`.`product_id`
    LEFT  JOIN `oc_seo_data` ON `oc_product`.`product_id` = `oc_seo_data`.`id`
    left JOIN `oc_url_alias` on `oc_seo_data`.`url_alias_id` = `oc_url_alias` .`url_alias_id`
    GROUP BY `oc_product`.`product_id`
```

Comment: Run `explain select ...` your query and share the result.

Comment: oc_product 1743
oc_product_to_category 57
oc_product_description 1
oc_category_description 17
oc_product_image 3277
oc_seo_data 4210
oc_url_alisa_id 1